# Symfony 5 Private chat with Pusher

Tags: javascript, symfony, sockets, chat, pusher

I've created a simple group chat application with `Symfony 5`, and now I'm trying to add `Socket` with `Pusher`.

For the moment it's working, but because I'm using a single `channel`, everytime a user post a message, this message appears on every conversation. That's why I would like to pass the `messaging_id` in the `channel name`, but it's not working.

I read on the doc I should use the prefix `private-` in my `channel name`, but with this the console is asking me to auth the user, and I don't know how do it because my user is already connected.

Here is my logic **controller** :

```
 // Pusher
        $options = array(
            'cluster' => 'eu',
            'useTLS' => true
        );
        $pusher = new Pusher(
            'ba75523bee28d7c644f2',
            '9597b6daf0fb4e20fda2',
            '1266737',
            $options
        );

        //New message
        $message = new Message();
        $form = $this->createForm(MessageType::class, $message);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $message->setAuthor($user);
            $message->setMessaging($messaging);
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($message);
            $entityManager->flush();

            $data = $message->getContent();

            if ($pusher->trigger('my-channel', 'my_event', $data)) {
                echo 'success';
            } else {
                header('', true, 403);
                echo 'error';
            }

            return new JsonResponse(Response::HTTP_OK);
        }
```

Here is my **Javascript** :

```
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

var pusher = new Pusher('ba75523bee28d7c644f2', {
    cluster: 'eu',
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');

channel.bind('my_event',
    function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('.lala').append('<li class = "chat-left"><div class="chat-text">' + data + '</div>');
    });

channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function (members) {
    console.log('successfully subscribed!');
});

function ajaxCall(ajax_url, ajax_data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajax_url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: ajax_data,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (msg) { }
    });
}
```

Here is the error if I use the `private-` prefix :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMg2P.png)

To summarize, I would like every message to only appear in the good conversation (Messages are of course saved in the database in the right conversation).
Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *have* to use private channels to have a channel per chat, but it does make sense - this would allow you to ensure the only users that are a member of the chat are able to subscribe to the channel (and therefore receive messages).

The error message received appears to indicate an error with the code at your auth endpoint. You can find details of the auth process and examples of auth endpoint code at https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/authenticating-users/.

If you are using the PHP library than the code needed to generate an auth token is detailed [in the Github repo](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php#authenticating-private-channels). This will need to be returned in response to the auth request

Comment: I found a solution, just use the messaging->getId() directly in the channel name trigger, and same in the javascript code, and it's working, maybe not the best solution but for the moment it's working